# Why is my profile messed up on a single site and how can I revert it?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, user-accounts

I was just asking a question on Gardening SE and suddenly my user name there is `a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75a`and my picture is replaced by a Gravatar. My location is also left blank.

Here's a [link to my profile there.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/14572/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae?tab=profile)

Curiously, my profiles on all other sites are fine.

I don't have a separate login for SE, I log in using my Google account. Nobody other than me has access to my Google account. I use two step authentication and I can see on "recent devices" in Google that no one but me has accessed my Google account. I only access SE from home, and nobody other than me has used my devices.

I tried to edit my Gardening SE profile back to the way I want it to be and I got the following message:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again on Jun 20 at 10:49

I'm assuming this is because I changed the "about me" on all SE sites two days ago.

I never edit my profiles individually. I always apply changes to all sites, using the same profile on all sites.

I have certainly not made such strange (or any) edits to my profile on Gardening SE.

Why did this happen, and how can I get my proper user name and picture back on Gardening SE? Do I really have to wait for a whole month? I want to use the site, and I want them to recognize me as the user they know. I don't want to wait a whole month.

Update: The Gardening SE moderator Niall C. helped me out, and he offered the following potentially relevant information:

> I changed your display name on Gardening & Landscaping back to "Fiksdal". Your profile history shows that your profile image (from your headshot on imgur.com to a gravatar), email, about me also changed at the same time as your display name on May 21. It also shows that I changed your profile image to a different gravatar when I changed your display name just now... weird! – Niall C. 1 hour ago

Comment: Try editing your profile on a different site, then select "Save and copy changes to all..." when you're done.

Comment: The bug affects many users all over the network: https://www.google.co.uk/#q=site:stackexchange.com+a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae

Comment: ...and it looks like [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277267/issue-when-joining-community) has become worse.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Any possible solution?

Comment: @Fiksdal real fix can only come from SE developers, I've pinged one in chat and got a reply: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4932157#4932157

Comment: @ShadowWizard Cool, thanks. How about editing my profile once? Could a mod help me override the once a month thing?

Comment: @Fiksdal is you change something in your profile here (e.g. adding something minor to About Me) then save to all profiles, what happens?

Comment: Anyway, moderator can indeed manually change your name, you can contact a site moderator [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed) and ask for such a name change. (e.g. "@NiallC. can you please change my display name to...") :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried changing the "About me" here on meta and applying it on all sites. The "About me" was changed on Gardening, but unfortunately the user name and Gravatar remained. Maybe if I add a space at the end of my user name, and apply it on all sites?

Comment: @ArtOfCode See my previous comment.

Comment: Looks like the system is smart enough to not let you bypass the 30 days rule, so I'm afraid pinging a moderator in chat is your only option. (even when the bug will be fixed, I highly doubt it will be "retroactive" since many users might have changed the name already)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Alright, thanks. I already pinged Niall. How can I see a list of mods on Gardening? I figured I would ping a few more.

Comment: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators - Niall is the only one who can be pinged. (the other two were not in the chat room for a while, so can't be pinged)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks so much for your help. I think what we have uncovered during this conversation could be an answer, so if you want to type something out I will accept and upvote. If you don't feel like it, I can also type something myself. But all the info really came from you.

Comment: Not sure about it. With bug reports, answers should come from SE developers who fix the bug. Sometimes answers can be posted with more details about the bug and ways to fix it, but not sure if this is proper here, since they're already aware of it. I'll give this a day or two, and hopefully you'll get official answer by then. (and a name change by the moderator even before. :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see. Yeah, the most important thing would be to solve the actual bug :)

Comment: I changed your display name on [gardening.se] back to "Fiksdal". Your profile history shows that your profile image (from your headshot on imgur.com to a gravatar), email, about me also changed at the same time as your display name on May 21. It also shows that I changed your profile image to a different gravatar when I changed your display name just now... weird!

Comment: @NiallC. Hey, thanks for helping! Wow, that's really weird. Anyway, my profile is nice again now, thanks :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Niall helped me out, and he came upon some interesting details, should I add them to OP for the benefit of the developers?

Comment: @Fiksdal Sure, can't hurt. We did have an issue a while back that resulted in a few broken profiles across the network, but I don't recall off hand if the timing lines up with your Gardening profile creation. Thanks!

Comment: Oh wait, it *switched* to that state after being normal for a while? That's... probably not good. :)

Comment: @Adam Yup... I had already been using  the site for a while. Well yeah, it sounds like a rather significant bug. I'm not sure what triggered it. It might have occurred at any time between the last time I asked a question and today without me noticing it.

Comment: @Fiksdal Yeah, for sure. If you have any additional details to add to your report, please do. I'll take a look at what's what first chance tomorrow.

Comment: @Adam OK! :) I added Niall C.'s details to OP.

Comment: @Adam this just happened to [another user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279851/profile-showing-wrong-information-after-copying-data-from-another-board), any update?

Comment: @Adam and [yet another](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281019/uuid-displayed-instead-of-username), any updates?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Digging...

Comment: @Fiksdal Do you happen to recall what you did before this happened? Did you edit your profile on another site and save changes to all communities (or just clicked "save profile")? Or was this done through a mobile app?

Comment: @AdamLear I edited the "About me" on all sites about two days before I noticed this problem. I don't remember which site I did it through, but  I applied it to all sites. I did it through a desktop web browser.

Comment: @AdamLear I've got the same issue, but I did not change anything on my profile after registration on the site where it happened, so that does not seem to be the issue for me. [profile page](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/18885/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae) . The strangest thing: my username is *excatly* the same, except I've got an `e` behind it: **a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae**

Comment: @Adam maybe it's something like what happened [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217031/152859)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Doubt it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out we were doing things ever so slightly out of order when creating users from the mobile app.

When we create a user object, we use `a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae` string as the initial name and it is later corrected to a display name we infer from the credential provider (e.g. Google), the sign up form, or if all else fails, the user id we're assigning to the user.

This was all fine and dandy until we refactored another method that created... well... I'm sure you can guess:

[image: CreateAllTheThingsThisPersonNeeds]

AccountSiteProfile creation is the thing that would persist the fake display name before it got corrected on the User.

The issue should be fixed now. And not to worry, we put a safeguard in place so that we're notified if this sort of thing ever happens again:

[image: WTF?! exception]

Comment: You really have a method called CreateAllTheThingsThisPersonNeeds in the actual code? Really? :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep. To be fair, it's not actually *all* the things, but CreateSomeOfTheThingsThisPersonNeeds is even sillier.

Comment: Just got [a fresh example of this bug](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/30601/user30601) created today. An existing user elsewhere, but just created an RPG.se account. (Note I've already reset the name to userxxxx.) Here's a chance to confirm that the new exception is properly catching and logging these. :)

Comment: I think I've came across this bug [too](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/110084/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae).

Comment: @haggai_e Sorry about that. Should be all fixed now. (A profile edit clears it right up now. :))

Comment: @AdamLear Thank you for fixing this.

Comment: It appears to have happened again: http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/401/what-happened-to-my-profile-on-this-site

Comment: @Adam [here too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290915/profile-name-and-icon-are-broken-but-only-on-coffee-se). Was the fix reverted?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, something else is busted. Fantastic.

Comment: oh my... so you'll have to dig it up from scratch? Also, should we close the other one as dupe of this? (removing the [tag:status-completed] in such case?)

Comment: @Adam bump... it [happened to Jason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292679/something-is-strange-about-my-login-on-at-least-one-site). Any chance to investigate again?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, on my list for when I'm on bug duty later this week. Not sure Jason's issue is the same thing, though.

Comment: @Adam *cough* "later this week" passed a bit ago... anyway, [here is another example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/347890/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae) - also part of [this new bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309299/meta-se-account-is-shown-3-times-in-accounts) (the display name was the GUID, user manually changed it). What's going on?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The new report is a different issue. I don't have a good theory there yet, except that I suspect something's busted in how mobile apps create users.

Comment: @Adam but it used to be fine for years, and now all those bugs...

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's almost like we keep making changes to the code and that has the potential to introduce new issues. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Seriously, though, the "guid as a display name" thing is generally a symptom that signals that *something* fell over during user creation. What that something is can vary wildly. There are a lot of things that happen in the process there.

Comment: @AdamLear - Happened a couple times the last couple days on Fitness. Ended up with 3 users named for the key.

Comment: Happened to me [5 days ago](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/19182/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae?tab=profile) signing up to communities from the android app seems to be a BadIdea™

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/400096/danis

Comment: @VictorVosMottor It might be better to link to their CGCC account(s): https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99104/danis