# UUID displayed instead of username

Tags: bug, profile-page, display-names

**For some reason, all of this has been fixed, somehow.** Thank you @null (Science fiction & fantasy mod) for changing it to 'Alex' and letting me change my name on other sites.

I've found a bug where my profile name appears as my UUID instead of my name…

> [image]

<s>It happens for:</s>

1. Movies and TV
2. Physics
3. Electrical Engineering
4. Super user
5. Puzzling
6. Programmers

Is this a bug or is this just me being inactive and having only 101 rep on those sites?

And for some sites, the default StackExchange icon is displayed (ex. Software Recommendations)

Comment: I see that as your username on the laptop, too. Maybe remove the app tag?

Comment: There is ongoing bug that triggers when copying data between sites, it's still not fixed. Changing your name manually on the affected site should work fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard When will it be fixed?

Comment: @Alex since Adam is now digging into it, I hope that soon, couple of days.

Comment: Unrelated note: you misspelled "you're" as "your" in your profile text...

Comment: @Laurel Better change that, whoops

Comment: @Alex Do you happen to recall what you did before this happened (around, say, June 24th)? Did you edit your profile on another site and save changes to all communities (or just clicked "save profile")? Or were you using a mobile app?

Comment: @AdamLear I might of, I know I did change my profile desc. A few times (maybe that day) because I was trying to think of what to say. I did save to all sites, too. I think I was either on Arqade or MSE on mobile site when I did it.