# Error joining community: not "trusted in other communities" rep

Tags: bug, reputation, superuser

I received an error message when I tried to join the Super User community.

I followed some instructions [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279526/why-is-my-profile-messed-up-on-a-single-site-and-how-can-i-revert-it) and fixed the issues with my profile. However, I'm still with only 1 reputation point on Super User.

Unlike the linked question, the issue I'm mentioning didn't happen at any point when several users were having this problem. So after 24 hours I don't have much hope that my reputation issue will be solved automatically.

What should I do to get SE to give me the 100+ rep bonus on Super User?

(By the way, I'm aware that issues should be addressed first in the respective communities, but I don't have enough reputation to bring this issue in the Super User meta.)