# Display Username bug

Tags: bug, android-app, display-names

I've a weird bug with my username on stack exchange and overflow.
When I post a comment or replay a question my user isn't DataHearth but : 
`a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae`

There's a screenshot

> [image: Question about XFCE DE]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device Model: MI 5s Plus
- OS Version: 7.0 (V9.5.2.0.NBGMIFA)

Comment: This was caused by a bug I created - my apologies!  Looks like you're all fixed up now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that on Ask Ubuntu, you have set a different user name then what you have on the other sites.

To fix that, open [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) using a desktop browser, and after signing in, press on your Avatar found on the top right of the page. Then press on *Edit profile & settings* found at the top left of the page. (Try using [this link](https://askubuntu.com/users/edit/820572/) to access that page. (This will only work for OP)) You will then see an option to change your user name. After picking your username, you can decide if you want to save changes to all sites or just the current one, using the option at the bottom of the page.